# src vs href on img tag IE

Tags: javascript

I have run into an issue IE 8 and IE 11 is treating src and href as the same thing for img tags -

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXqzrV

```
<img id="logo" alt="Rent.com" src="http://rent.qa.assets.rentpathcdn.com/assets/rent-logo-eb029594.png">

var a = document.getElementById('logo');
alert(a.src);
alert(a.href);
```

this occurs when I do not have an href attribute specified for img node, just a src.

I'm writing a custom extension that collects information about a clicked node. 
is there a potential work around for this issue, or will I have to code around the non existent attributes?

Comment: `a.href` is a DOM property, not an HTML attribute. Does `a.getAttribute("href")` still return the same thing as `a.src`?

Comment: this works and gives me what I want - but why? should I prefer getAttribute for collection of future dom values?

Comment: What problem did this cause .. ?

Comment: @Ifender, *dom values* is equivocal. From your question, you need attributes, so you should ask for them, not for DOM properties. DOM properties are often, but not always, mapped to HTML attributes, and URL properties such as `src` and `href` are good examples of *not always*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE does not support `href` in `img` HTML elements.

> The img element does not support the HREF content attribute. In addition, the href property is read-only for the img Document Object Model (DOM) object.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc848861(v=vs.85).aspx

I would stick to what @Frederic mentioned above and use `a.getAttribute('href')` instead.

Comment: using getAttribute solved the issue instead of reading the dom property off of the node in question